# Li-ion battery overcharging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

We're charging a Li-ion battery pack with a direct 5.2 V input from a regulator while we always have a load of at least 70 mA in parallel to the battery. We can not switch off the load. We have found that the batteries overcharge, meaning the battery protection PCB does not work correctly. We've tried a few different protection ICs. The following image is the latest design we have tried:
[image]

It seems that when the battery is fully charged and placed on the charger, it cuts off correctly, but when it's not fully charged, the cut of does not work.
The following image shows the overcharging (we have had batteries charging to 4.5 V before the charging is removed). The image shows the voltage measured over the battery, and the current measured over the parallel resistors (current is absolute and does not show direction)
[image]

It seems that the CO pin does not function correctly. I've measured the potential over CO and B-. CO goes low for a short interval and then goes high again. This pattern matches the current flowing into the battery:
CO Pin:
[image]

Current into battery:
[image]

I'm wondering if this might have something to do with the constant load (I'm still testing charging without load). Another possibility I think is the threshold voltage of the MOSFET (this will be my next test). Ablic's datasheet states:

> If the threshold voltage of a FET is low, the FET may not cut the charging current.
> If a FET with a threshold voltage equal to or higher than the overdischarge detection voltage is used, discharging may
> be stopped before overdischarge is detected.

I'm not sure about this as most suggested MOSFETS have a 0.6 V threshold or close to 0.6 V.

Any suggestions on what to test of how to fix this issue? We are currently working on an upgrade with a proper battery charger and system switch off, but we need to get an interim solution.

Comment: Realying on protection to do charge termination sounds like a very bad idea. Can't you make sure the charge is terminated at the correct voltage in the first place?

Comment: I agree. All these protections are fault handling mechanics, they're not designed to be used on a daily basis, and you can't predict how it will behave in any kind of long term scenario. Why not put a generic charging IC between 5V and battery? They terminate charging, do trickle charging and can even control thermals, even in SOT-23 package. You can have 5V to load and battery voltage to load join via two schottkys or put ideal diodes in there (real thing).

Comment: This is the wrong way to use lithium batteries and liable to cause overheating and possibly fire or explosion. There are numerous questions about charging and switching between battery and power supply on this site, have a search.

Comment: I understand that this is the wrong method. We've been contracted to add a new BMS which will handle the charging, but in the mean time, our client has thousands of these battery packs in the field and they need a quick way to improve battery stability. I'm trying to understand why the protection PCB isn't cutting off the battery at over charge limits.

Answer (score 1):

Battery protection ICs like the [S-8261](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/battery_protection/S8261_E.pdf) are designed to disconnect the battery under fault conditions such as over-voltage during charging, over-current, short circuit or low voltage during discharge. They are **not** supposed to be used as a charge terminating device.

To avoid false tripping the over-voltage point is set **higher** than the normal maximum charging voltage, with a delay before tripping. A small amount of [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Electronic_circuits) is also applied to ensure that it stays tripped until the charging voltage is significantly reduced. Depending on the variant of S-8261 you are using, this hysteresis could be as low as 0.1 V.

Your graph of absolute current draw shows random steps in the current which suggests the load is drawing pulses of current at a high frequency. This could be causing the S-8261 to cut in and out when close to the over-charge threshold. The trip delay would then cause the battery to continue being charged at a lower rate. In the graph we do see this, along with a small voltage step at ~4.3 V which is probably the IC's over-voltage trip point.

You may be able to mitigate this over-charge effect by adding bulk capacitance across the load to smooth out voltage variations when the battery is disconnected. However this may not completely eliminate the problem of the battery getting a higher charge voltage than it should.

You don't have a CVCC charger in the circuit so you don't have to worry about tripping before it reaches the constant voltage phase (that it doesn't have). Therefore you could use a variant of the S-8261 with a lower overcharge detection voltage such as 4.1 V. Alternatively you could (and probably should) add a proper charging circuit with load sharing as described [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf). Charger ICs may also be available that have built-in load sharing capability.